# Changing framework 4.0 to 2.0 without affecting any reference

Tags: .net-4.0, reference, .net-2.0

I have developed a Windows application in the 4.0 framework. After deploying my application I have tried to install it in a Windows XP SP2 system, but when I try it I get some kind of **requirement error**. So I decided to change my application from 4.0 to the 2.0 framework so that it can be installed in any windows OS. Before that I tried with 3.5 and 3.0 but the framework's setup size exceeded 200mb, so I chose 2.0 because it already comes along with windows xp or later. The problem  I am having is while changing my framework from 4.0 to 2.0 i'm getting reference problems with `system.core` and `system.linq` so now I cant build my project. What needs to be done to fix these reference errors?

Comment: "i came up with 2.0 because it already comes along with windows xp or later" That is not true. [XP does not include](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework#Versions) any version of the CLR, Tablet / Media center editions being an edge case - and they only came with 1.0.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `System.Linq`, for example, didn't exist in .NET 2.  If you are using anything that required `System.Linq` methods (such as LINQ or any extension methods), you'll have to rewrite that portion of your code to use .NET 2 only options.

Personally, I would just target .NET 3.5sp1 or .NET 4, and include the web installer, as this is a small addition to your deployment (the [4.0 web installer](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17851) is under 1mb - many installers include a way to just package this instead of the full framework).  Most systems already have .NET 3.5sp1 (and many have 4.0), so the effort to include this in your deployment is typically far smaller than trying to rework your application to avoid it.